# how to generate multidimensional array from array value

Tags: php, laravel

i'm new in php and i stuck some where actually i need to generate multidimensional array  from array value.
e.g my array is like that and remember all array and value are dynamic

```
array(
0 => array(
    0 => "college"
    1 => "student"
    2 => "contact"
),
1 => array(
    0 => "college"
    1 => "parents"
    2 => "contact"
),
2 => array(
    0 => "school"
    1 => "parents"
    2 => "contact"
),
3 => array(
    0 => "school"
    1 => "student"
    2 => "contact"
))
```

and i want result like that

```
 0 => array (
"college" => array(
    "student" => array (
        "contact" => array (
          "address" => "address_value"
        )
    ),
    "parents" => array (
        "contact" => array (
          "address" => "address_value"
        )
    ),
),
"school" => array(
    "student" => array (
        "contact" => array (
          "address" => "address_value"
        )
    ),
    "parents" => array (
        "contact" => array (
          "address" => "address_value"
        )
    ),
)),
```

i want to generate multidimensional array till the array value and last array has some value

can any one help me with standard way.
help will appreciated..
thanks in advance

Comment: What did you mean by `array:5` ?

Comment: @Syscall it's just typo mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
function group($a, $level, $previous = '') {
    $b = [];
    for( $i = 0, $n = count($a); $i < $n; ++$i ) {
        if( $level > 0 && $a[$i][$level-1] !== $previous  ) {
            continue;
        }
        $key = $a[$i][$level];
        $b[$key] = [];
        if( array_key_exists($level+1, $a[$i]) ) {
            $b[$key] = group($a, $level+1, $key);
        }
    }
    return $b;
}

print_r(group($a, 0));
```

Output:

```
Array(
    [college] => Array (
        [student] => Array (
            [contact] => Array ()
        )
        [parents] => Array (
            [contact] => Array ()
        )
    )
    [school] => Array (
        [student] => Array (
            [contact] => Array ()
        )
        [parents] => Array (
            [contact] => Array ()
        )
    )
)
```

Using @AlivetoDie example:

```
Array (
    [college] => Array (
        [student] => Array (
            [contact] => Array ()
        )
        [parents] => Array (
             [contact] => Array ()
        ) 
    ) 
    [school] => Array (
        [parents] => Array (
            [contact] => Array ()
        )
        [student] => Array (
             [contact] => Array ()
        ) 
        [data] => Array (
             [contact] => Array()
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: it will not work in case of:- `$a = array(
    0 => array(
        0 => "college",
        1 => "student",
        2 => "contact"
    ),
    1 => array(
        0 => "college",
        1 => "parents",
        2 => "contact"
    ),
    2 => array(
        0 => "school",
        1 => "parents",
        2 => "contact"
    ),
    3 => array(
        0 => "school",
        1 => "student",
        2 => "contact"
    ),
    4 => array(
        0 => "school",
        1 => "data",
        2 => "contact"
    )
);`

Comment: seems correct now. But need to be checked with different structure+values.(And that's OP task, not mine).+1

Comment: @myxobek little bit confusion was there when i pass only `$a = array(0 => "college",1 => "student",2 => "contact");` at that time it's show me `array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given` because at that time i passing only array. is there any other way to fix it?

Comment: @RyanDen function expects your array would be similar to one you provided in question description. Array in comment is not similar to that one in description. It should work when you provide `$a = array(0 => array(0 => "college",1 => "student",2 => "contact"));`

Comment: @myxobek ok fine got it i can pass array properly..
thank you for responding